# Use data from different pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have two pipelines, "gameEngineEvents" and "userEvents" that consume from equivalent pubsub topics. A userEvent might have one or many gameEngineEvents.

When a gameEngineEvent happens I want to check if there is a userEvent that has a reference to that gameEngineEvent, run some logic and then publish a new message to a third pubsub topic.

So, is it possible to do something like this only in dataflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly possible. What you will want to use here is a `CoGroupByKey` which will shuffle the "gameEngineEvent"s with a certain key to the same machine as the "userEvent" with that key in order to process them together a perform a certain logic on them. You will end up with 2 iterables for that key which you can use in your processing.

More info on the specifics of `CoGroupByKey` can be found [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms-gbk).

Since these are PubSub topics and you are probably coping with an unbounded source you'll probably also want to look at [Windowing](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing), in order to set borders on which events you want to perform the processing on.